# Golang HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: authentication, go

I am new in golang.

I am trying to call JIRA rest api with basic auth, but getting following error

```
&{401 Unauthorized 401 HTTP/2.0 2 0
map[X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff]
Set-Cookie:[JSESSIONID=E08620; Path=/;
Secure; HttpOnly studio.crowd.tokenkey="";
Domain=.test.atlassian.net; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10
GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly studio.crowd.tokenkey="";
Domain=.test.atlassian.net; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10
GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly] Server:[nginx] Date:[Mon, 09 Jan 2017
05:18:29 GMT] Content-Type:[text/html;charset=UTF-8]
X-Arequestid:[648x20759x1] X-Seraph-Loginreason:[AUTHENTICATED_FAILED]
Www-Authenticate:[OAuth
realm="https%3A%2F%2Ftest.atlassian.net"]] {0xc42039b900} -1 []
false false map[] 0xc4200ce0f0 0xc4202b0420}
```

My code is

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

const (
    USERNAME = ""
    PASSWORD = ""
    URL      = "https://test.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/SLUB-7194"
)

func main() {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", URL, nil)
    req.SetBasicAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    cli := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := cli.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(resp);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've met strange problems connecting to Jira API. Sometimes you need to allow API connections explicitly. Sometimes you have to make an OpenAPI dance to get a credentials. Not all packages work well with it. So I recommend getting sure problem not in API itself, e.g. with CURL or another handy http debugging tool like `httpie`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As seen in [`Netflix-Skunkworks/go-jira/cli.go`](https://github.com/Netflix-Skunkworks/go-jira/blob/5a71939a27c978a8e7d19968dc23908197484827/cli.go#L221), you might need to login first, then request your jira ticket.

```
func (c *Cli) makeRequest(req *http.Request) (resp *http.Response, err error) {
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    if source, ok := c.opts["password-source"]; ok && !strings.HasSuffix(req.URL.Path, "/rest/auth/1/session") {
        user, _ := c.opts["user"].(string)
        password := c.GetPass(user)
        if password == "" {
            log.Warning("No password for user %s in %s, please run the 'login' command first", user, source)
        } else {
            req.SetBasicAuth(user, password)
        }
}
```